# Differential element of current question

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, magnetostatics

I'm watching some basic magnetic field derivations and most of the proofs use the differential element $dI$.

Let's say a wire carries a current I. When we take a very small current $dI$ though , shouldn't it have the same value as the current running through the wire? Also,if the current is constant shouldn't $dI$ be zero? What is actually a differential element? Maybe that's the question I should be asking.

The only time that it makes sense to me is in 3d conductors where the current varies inside them.

One of the examples I had trouble with was while using Ampere's law to find B inside a solinoid. The $I_{enclosed}$ is different from the total current. Isn't I just a rate of movement? How are you supposed to enclose it? Maybe it's actually the charge you enclose ? No, that would be Gauss' law.

Anyway, I hope you see what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current J is localized. I is the flux of the current through the transversal surface of the wire. J is called current density for a reason, it is a "density" of current, it doesn't depend on the wire. I is the total current, it depends on the transversal area of the wire. I don't like to use dI, it is confusing. Instead use I(enc). If the current J is constant everywhere, then I(enc) depends on the radius you take the circular surface at, and I is understood generally as a known value that coincides with I(enc) when the radius of the surface you take is the same as the radius of the wire.